# Using .map() to find an element in a list results in 'undefined' elements

Tags: javascript

I have an array of JSON. I would get this first array element where `element[i].country` is equal to a value.

Actually I use the `map` method.

```
this.dataFiltered = data.map(elm => {
  if (elm.country == this.country) return elm;
});
```

The `data` array:

```
[
    {
        "elm1": "String",
        "country": "France"
    }
    ,
    {
        "elm1": "String",
        "country": "Italie"
    }
]
```

When `country` is `"France"`
I get `dataFilter` equal to

> [
>       {
>           "elm1": "String",
>           "country": "France"
>       },
>       undefined   ]

What I expect is.

> [
>       {
>           "elm1": "String",
>           "country": "France"
>       }]

So I have found  `find` method that looks for the first object.

But when I replace `map` with `find` I don't get any result.

Comment: Have you considerd using .filter?

Comment: Have you tried putting a else condition there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) as below. The `find()` method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function.

```js
var data = [{ "elm1": "String","country": "France"}, {"elm1": "String", "country": "Italie"}];
var country = "France";

var dataFilter = data.find( item => item.country == country);
console.log(dataFilter)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.filter()` method.

```
data.filter(elm => elm.country === this.country)[0]
```

This will return the first matching element (if there are any matches).

`.map()` goes through all elements and by default replaces the current element with `undefined` if you don't return a value explicitly. That's why you have "holes" in your list.

Comment: *This will return an array with **one element** (if there are any matches).* Actually, this will return an array of all matching elements if you use `.filter()` and only one element.

Comment: @chŝdk, thanks, I corrected my answer. I thought the countries will always be unique so I left out the explanation of what will actually happen.

Comment: Thanks How to write that in multiple lines ?

Answer (score 0):

Just take [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and take the boolean value for the decision if the element has to be included or not.

```
this.dataFiltered = data.filter(elm => elm.country == this.country);
```

`Array#map` returns for every element a new value. In your case, it it `undefined`, the standard return value of a function.